# How to assign a tty to a process?

Tags: terminal, tty

I can configure a command which will be run without a tty (similar to a cronjob). The problem is that the binary to be run seems to require a terminal. Is there a way to run a process with a new tty assigned? I don't really care about the output, but the binary seems to fail without it.

I tried to run it with tmux, but it seems like tmux fails if there is no terminal.

Comment: Likely the best way would be to use pseudo terminals for this.  You need to have a consumer too though.  This is how things like tmux and screen (and ssh) work.  I may write a longer answer later.